# Randomizing .click and .dblclick

Tags: jquery, random, click, double-click

I'm trying to get jquery to randomize if a single click or a doubleclick is needed to function something but somehow, I'm getting stuck in every way I've tried it. I know this shouldn't be done but I'm doing a study on distractions. :D

This is my code atm:

```
var rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
if(rnd != 0) {
     $('.energie div.article').click(function() {

     $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
     $('.energie div.article').hide(),

     $(this).next('div.detail').show();
     $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
     };
 else {
     $('.energie div.article').dblclick(function() {

     $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
     $('.energie div.article').hide(),

     $(this).next('div.detail').show();
     $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
     };
 };
```

Comment: What do you see? How is this failing for you?

Comment: well it simply destroys all the other code ^^

Comment: Can you provide HTML or a working demo? Maybe at jsfiddle.net

Comment: How random do you want it?  On page load?  Or every click/dblclick it should be random which one sets it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//No more code redundancy - use a function :)
function handler() {
    $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
    $('.energie div.article').hide();
    $(this).next('div.detail').show();
    $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();

    //"reroll" the handler
    bind();
}

//bind your event handler here, "50/50 probability"
function bind() {
    //random whether it will be dblclick or click
    var whatHandler = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'dblclick' :'click';

    //bind our handlers to a namespace called 'test' for easy unbinding
    $('div').unbind('.test').bind(whatHandler + '.test', handler);
}

$(function() {
   //on doc ready, bind our handler for the first time
   bind();
});
```

See simplified version here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FvScr/10/

Comment: That sounds very logic thanks. It does work but it only triggers on dblclick. Could it be that Math.random is very often < 0.5 ? how could I get it to be a 50:50 chance on the handlers ..?

Comment: hmm, but if I test the example on http://jsfiddle.net/FvScr/ it also always triggers with a singleclick... where could the problem be?

Comment: Weird, that's not happening for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using firefox. ah if I update it, it switches to the other handler. but how can it be varied without updating anything? I would need a function that keeps "rerolling" the math.random is that the solution?

Comment: Ahh :)  That's what I was asking in your question comments... fiddle to come.

Comment: hmm works perfect on fiddle but has problems with the function i'm trying to trigger. I think because of the bind class .test... when I use it with my function, if it's a single click handler it works fine but if its dblclick it somehow my articles are all hidden and only appear on the 2nd attempt to get them back and then again it will be dblclick again so... once dblclick => always dblclick. actually does it have to be a div for binding ..?

Comment: I think i've got the solution... i changed $('div').unbind('.test') to $('div.article').unbind('.test') and I think this works well at least it works for now I'll test it through to see if there are any issues :)

Comment: Cool, well hope it works out.  Consider upvoting/accepting if this has helped you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)

if(rnd != 0) {
     $('.energie div.article').click(function() {
        $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
        $('.energie div.article').hide();
        $(this).next('div.detail').show();
        $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
} else {
     $('.energie div.article').dblclick(function() {

        $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
        $('.energie div.article').hide();

         $(this).next('div.detail').show();
        $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
 }
```

You had a ; behind the } closing the if and the also, also a , after the hide() function

Comment: thanks, now the site is showing properly again, but the click problem is still there. Now neiter a double-click nor a single click triggers anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Your's is not well formed:

```
var rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if(rnd != 0) {
     $('.energie div.article').click(function() {

         $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
         $('.energie div.article').hide(),

         $(this).next('div.detail').show();
         $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
 } else {
     $('.energie div.article').dblclick(function() {

         $('#maincontent').css('height', '100%');        
         $('.energie div.article').hide(),

         $(this).next('div.detail').show();
         $('#numbersenergie div').removeClass();
     });
 }
```

Comment: thanks aswell, syntax is now perfect but still nothing triggers :( maybe i got the idea wrong, does this code random my var rnd and if rnd is 0 you just need a single click to trigger and if var is 1 you need a double click to trigger..? there is no code around it for this function it's just this.